# Docker container keeps coming back

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gitlab-ce

I have installed gitlab-ce on my server with the following `docker.compose.yml` :

```yaml
gitlab:
  image: 'gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest'
  hostname: 'gitlab.devhunt.eu'
  restart: 'always'
  environment:
    # ...
  volumes:
    - '/var/lib/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab'
    - '/var/lib/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab'
    - '/var/lib/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab'
```

I used it for a while and now I want to remove it. I noticed that when I did `docker stop gitlab` (which is the container name), it kept coming back so I figured it was because of the `restart: always`. Thus the struggle begins :

- I tried `docker update --restart=no gitlab` before `docker stop gitlab`. Still coming back.
- I did `docker stop gitlab && docker rm gitlab`. It got deleted but came back soon after
- I went to change the `docker-compose.yml` to `restart: no`, did `docker-compose down`. The container got stopped and deleted but came back soon after
- I did `docker-compose up` to apply the change in the compose file, checked that it was successfully taken into account with `docker inspect -f "{{ .HostConfig.RestartPolicy }}" gitlab`. The response was `{no 0}`. I did `docker-compose down`. Again, it got stopped and deleted but came back soon after
- I did `docker stop gitlab && docker rm gitlab && docker image rm fcc1e4187c43` (the image hash I had for docker-ce). The container got stopped, deleted and the image got deleted. And it seemed that I had finally managed to kill the beast... one hour later, gitlab container was reinstalled with another image hash (`3cc8e8a0764d`) and the container was starting.

I would stop the docker daemon but I have production websites and databases running and I would like to avoid downtime if possible. Any idea what I can do ?

Comment: Note to self: the 40G docker.raw (probabyl not related to this question but it is the first result in google) is just an apparent size, not actual size.

Answer (score 1):

you-ve set the restart policy to always, set it to unless-stoped.

check the docs https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/start-containers-automatically/

Comment: have you tried updating you docker compose file as well ?, because basically the compose file should act as the source of truth for you container. when you do docker-compose down you cannt do that from any location, you should pass your location of your docker-compose file, and by checking its state docker knows what resources should it dispose of

Comment: I ended up restarting my docker daemon, I was just curious if I did something wrong or if this was a bug that needed to be filed